# Always show Previous & Next links using CodeIgniter Pagination Class

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination, codeigniter-2

**Problem Description**
When I'm at the first page, the `previous` link is not showing up and so do the `next` link when I'm at the last page. I set `$config['prev_link']='previous'` and `$config['next_link']='next'`.

**Question**
How to **always** present, using the CodeIgniter pagination class, the **Previous** and **Next** links as `<p>` tags when they are not in used?

**Update**
End up Solving it myself. See solution below. Working on v2.1.3

Comment: Why would you show the links when they are useless on those pages? That doesn't make it very user friendly and will just confuse visitors.

Comment: Hi @crypticツ, my idea is to have a fixed previous and next icons and the page's number to run in between it instead of shifting all the page's numbers every time or hide the unnecessary previous/next links. My goal is instead of hiding it, I would like to present it as <p> tags and apply CSS on it so it will be presented as un-active link.

Comment: @crypticツ, your thoughts about my solution...?

Comment: I would have approached it differently. Well you know that on the last page there is no next link and on the first page there is no previous link. Well if you know the item count and how many items per page you know which page will be the last and of course you know which page will be the first. So what I would have done is just checked to see if the URI segment is for first page or last page which I know will not contain the links and then echo out the disabled next/prev text version on those specific pages. So no need to extend class.

Comment: @crypticツ I took the approach of the CodeIgniter team and added two variables so I could control the appearance of the previous/next links but I must say that your solution is very nice, plain and simple. Thx!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> **Here is the Solution:**

1. Extend Codeigniter pagination class by creating a new file: `MY_Pagination.php` and placing it in the `application/library` folder.
2. Change all variables and classes prefix declarations from `protected` to `public`.
3. Define two public variable in MY_Pagination.php: `$display_prev_link` and `$display_next_link` and set it to `FALSE`.
4. In the create_links() function, add to the end of the `if ($this->prev_link !== FALSE && $this->cur_page !== 1)` statement an `elseif` statement:

   ```
   elseif ($this->display_prev_link && $this->cur_page === 1)
       $output .= $this->prev_tag_open.'<span>'.$this->prev_link.'</span>'.$this->next_tag_close;
   ```

   and another `elseif` statement to the end of the `if ($this->next_link !== FALSE && $this->cur_page < $num_pages)` statement:

   ```
   elseif ($this->display_next_link && $this->cur_page >= $num_pages)
       $output .= $this->next_tag_open.'<span>'.$this->next_link.'</span>'.$this->next_tag_close;
   ```

**So Now,**

By defining `$config['display_prev_link']` and `$config['display_prev_link']` equal to `TRUE` or `FALSE`, you can control the presentation of the `Previous` and `Next` links.

Here is the complete `application/library/MY_Pagination.php` file:

```
<?php  

// Extends the Pagination Class
// Add an option of presenting the PREVIOUS and NEXT links when they're not needed.
// by setting $display_prev_link - and - $display_next_link to true

// !!! EDITIONS => LINES 263 AND 316 !!!

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Pagination extends CI_Pagination {

    public $display_prev_link = false;
    public $display_next_link = false;

    public $base_url        = '';
    public $prefix      = '';
    public $suffix      = '';
    public $total_rows      = 0;
    public $per_page        = 10;
    public $num_links       = 2;
    public $cur_page        = 0;
    public $use_page_numbers    = FALSE;
    public $first_link      = '&lsaquo; First';
    public $next_link       = '&gt;';
    public $prev_link       = '&lt;';
    public $last_link       = 'Last &rsaquo;';
    public $uri_segment     = 3;
    public $full_tag_open   = '';
    public $full_tag_close  = '';
    public $first_tag_open  = '';
    public $first_tag_close = '';
    public $last_tag_open   = '';
    public $last_tag_close  = '';
    public $first_url       = '';
    public $cur_tag_open        = '<strong>';
    public $cur_tag_close   = '</strong>';
    public $next_tag_open   = '';
    public $next_tag_close  = '';
    public $prev_tag_open   = '';
    public $prev_tag_close  = '';
    public $num_tag_open        = '';
    public $num_tag_close   = '';
    public $page_query_string   = FALSE;
    public $query_string_segment = 'per_page';
    public $display_pages   = TRUE;
    public $_attributes     = '';
    public $_link_types     = array();
    public $reuse_query_string   = FALSE;
    public $data_page_attr  = 'data-ci-pagination-page';

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param   array   $params Initialization parameters
     * @return  void
     */
    public function __construct($params = array())
    {
        $this->initialize($params);
        log_message('debug', 'Pagination Class Initialized');
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Initialize Preferences
     *
     * @param   array   $params Initialization parameters
     * @return  void
     */
    public function initialize($params = array())
    {
        $attributes = array();

        if (isset($params['attributes']) && is_array($params['attributes']))
        {
            $attributes = $params['attributes'];
            unset($params['attributes']);
        }

        // Deprecated legacy support for the anchor_class option
        // Should be removed in CI 3.1+
        if (isset($params['anchor_class']))
        {
            empty($params['anchor_class']) OR $attributes['class'] = $params['anchor_class'];
            unset($params['anchor_class']);
        }

        $this->_parse_attributes($attributes);

        if (count($params) > 0)
        {
            foreach ($params as $key => $val)
            {
                if (isset($this->$key))
                {
                    $this->$key = $val;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Generate the pagination links
     *
     * @return  string
     */
    public function create_links()
    {
        // If our item count or per-page total is zero there is no need to continue.
        if ($this->total_rows === 0 OR $this->per_page === 0)
        {
            return '';
        }

        // Calculate the total number of pages
        $num_pages = (int) ceil($this->total_rows / $this->per_page);

        // Is there only one page? Hm... nothing more to do here then.
        if ($num_pages === 1)
        {
            //$uri_page_number = 1;
            //return '';
        }

        // Set the base page index for starting page number
        $base_page = ($this->use_page_numbers) ? 1 : 0;

        // Determine the current page number.
        $CI =& get_instance();

        // See if we are using a prefix or suffix on links
        if ($this->prefix !== '' OR $this->suffix !== '')
        {
            $this->cur_page = (int) str_replace(array($this->prefix, $this->suffix), '', $CI->uri->rsegment($this->uri_segment));
        }

        if ($CI->config->item('enable_query_strings') === TRUE OR $this->page_query_string === TRUE)
        {
            if ($CI->input->get($this->query_string_segment) != $base_page)
            {
                $this->cur_page = (int) $CI->input->get($this->query_string_segment);
            }
        }
        elseif ( ! $this->cur_page && $CI->uri->segment($this->uri_segment) !== $base_page)
        {
            $this->cur_page = (int) $CI->uri->rsegment($this->uri_segment);
        }

        // Set current page to 1 if it's not valid or if using page numbers instead of offset
        if ( ! is_numeric($this->cur_page) OR ($this->use_page_numbers && $this->cur_page === 0))
        {
            $this->cur_page = $base_page;
        }

        $this->num_links = (int) $this->num_links;

        if ($this->num_links < 1)
        {
            show_error('Your number of links must be a positive number.');
        }

        // Is the page number beyond the result range?
        // If so we show the last page
        if ($this->use_page_numbers)
        {
            if ($this->cur_page > $num_pages)
            {
                $this->cur_page = $num_pages;
            }
        }
        elseif ($this->cur_page > $this->total_rows)
        {
            $this->cur_page = ($num_pages - 1) * $this->per_page;
        }

        $uri_page_number = $this->cur_page;

        if ( ! $this->use_page_numbers)
        {
            $this->cur_page = (int) floor(($this->cur_page/$this->per_page) + 1);
        }

        // Calculate the start and end numbers. These determine
        // which number to start and end the digit links with
        $start  = (($this->cur_page - $this->num_links) > 0) ? $this->cur_page - ($this->num_links - 1) : 1;
        $end    = (($this->cur_page + $this->num_links) < $num_pages) ? $this->cur_page + $this->num_links : $num_pages;

        // Is pagination being used over GET or POST? If get, add a per_page query
        // string. If post, add a trailing slash to the base URL if needed
        if ($CI->config->item('enable_query_strings') === TRUE OR $this->page_query_string === TRUE)
        {
            $segment = (strpos($this->base_url, '?')) ? '&amp;' : '?';
            $this->base_url = rtrim($this->base_url).$segment.$this->query_string_segment.'=';
        }
        else
        {
            $this->base_url = rtrim($this->base_url, '/') .'/';
        }

        // And here we go...
        $output = '';
        $query_string = '';

        // Add anything in the query string back to the links
        // Note: Nothing to do with query_string_segment or any other query string options
        if ($this->reuse_query_string === TRUE)
        {
            $get = $CI->input->get();

            // Unset the controll, method, old-school routing options
            unset($get['c'], $get['m'], $get[$this->query_string_segment]);

            if ( ! empty($get))
            {
                // Put everything else onto the end
                $query_string = (strpos($this->base_url, '?') !== FALSE ? '&amp;' : '?')
                        .http_build_query($get, '', '&amp;');

                // Add this after the suffix to put it into more links easily
                $this->suffix .= $query_string;
            }
        }

        // Render the "First" link
        if ($this->first_link !== FALSE && $this->cur_page > ($this->num_links + 1))
        {
            $first_url = ($this->first_url === '') ? $this->base_url : $this->first_url;

            // Take the general parameters, and squeeze this pagination-page attr in there for JS fw's
            $attributes = sprintf('%s %s="%d"', $this->_attributes, $this->data_page_attr, 1);

            $output .= $this->first_tag_open.'<a href="'.$first_url.'"'.$attributes.$this->_attr_rel('start').'>'
                .$this->first_link.'</a>'.$this->first_tag_close;
        }

        // Render the "previous" link
        if ($this->prev_link !== FALSE && $this->cur_page !== 1)
        {
            $i = ($this->use_page_numbers) ? $uri_page_number - 1 : $uri_page_number - $this->per_page;

            // Take the general parameters, and squeeze this pagination-page attr in there for JS fw's
            $attributes = sprintf('%s %s="%d"', $this->_attributes, $this->data_page_attr, (int) $i);

            if ($i === $base_page && $this->first_url !== '')
            {
                $output .= $this->prev_tag_open.'<a href="'.$this->first_url.$query_string.'"'.$attributes.$this->_attr_rel('prev').'>'
                    .$this->prev_link.'</a>'.$this->prev_tag_close;
            }
            else
            {
                $append = ($i === $base_page) ? $query_string : $this->prefix.$i.$this->suffix;
                $output .= $this->prev_tag_open.'<a href="'.$this->base_url.$append.'"'.$attributes.$this->_attr_rel('prev').'>'
                    .$this->prev_link.'</a>'.$this->prev_tag_close;
            }

        } 
// !!!!!!!! START EDITION !!!!!!!!!!
        elseif ($this->display_prev_link && $this->cur_page === 1) {
                $output .= $this->prev_tag_open.'<span>'.$this->prev_link.'</span>'.$this->next_tag_close;
            }
// !!!!!!!! END EDITION !!!!!!!!!!

        // Render the pages
        if ($this->display_pages !== FALSE)
        {
            // Write the digit links
            for ($loop = $start -1; $loop <= $end; $loop++)
            {
                $i = ($this->use_page_numbers) ? $loop : ($loop * $this->per_page) - $this->per_page;

                // Take the general parameters, and squeeze this pagination-page attr in there for JS fw's
                $attributes = sprintf('%s %s="%d"', $this->_attributes, $this->data_page_attr, (int) $i);

                if ($i >= $base_page)
                {
                    if ($this->cur_page === $loop)
                    {
                        $output .= $this->cur_tag_open.$loop.$this->cur_tag_close; // Current page
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $n = ($i === $base_page) ? '' : $i;
                        if ($n === '' && ! empty($this->first_url))
                        {
                            //$output .= $this->num_tag_open.'<a href="'.$this->first_url.$query_string.'"'.$attributes.$this->_attr_rel('start').'>'
                            //  .$loop.'</a>'.$this->num_tag_close;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $append = ($n === '') ? $query_string : $this->prefix.$n.$this->suffix;
                            $output .= $this->num_tag_open.'<a href="'.$this->base_url.$append.'"'.$attributes.$this->_attr_rel('start').'>'
                                .$loop.'</a>'.$this->num_tag_close;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Render the "next" link
        if ($this->next_link !== FALSE && $this->cur_page < $num_pages)
        {
            $i = ($this->use_page_numbers) ? $this->cur_page + 1 : $this->cur_page * $this->per_page;

            // Take the general parameters, and squeeze this pagination-page attr in there for JS fw's
            $attributes = sprintf('%s %s="%d"', $this->_attributes, $this->data_page_attr, (int) $i);

            $output .= $this->next_tag_open.'<a href="'.$this->base_url.$this->prefix.$i.$this->suffix.'"'.$attributes
                .$this->_attr_rel('next').'>'.$this->next_link.'</a>'.$this->next_tag_close;
        } 
// !!!!!!!! START EDITION !!!!!!!!!!
        elseif ($this->display_next_link && $this->cur_page >= $num_pages) {
            $output .= $this->next_tag_open.'<span>'.$this->next_link.'</span>'.$this->next_tag_close;
        }
// !!!!!!!! END EDITION !!!!!!!!!!

        // Render the "Last" link
        if ($this->last_link !== FALSE && ($this->cur_page + $this->num_links) < $num_pages)
        {
            $i = ($this->use_page_numbers) ? $num_pages : ($num_pages * $this->per_page) - $this->per_page;

            // Take the general parameters, and squeeze this pagination-page attr in there for JS fw's
            $attributes = sprintf('%s %s="%d"', $this->_attributes, $this->data_page_attr, (int) $i);

            $output .= $this->last_tag_open.'<a href="'.$this->base_url.$this->prefix.$i.$this->suffix.'"'.$attributes.'>'
                .$this->last_link.'</a>'.$this->last_tag_close;
        }

        // Kill double slashes. Note: Sometimes we can end up with a double slash
        // in the penultimate link so we'll kill all double slashes.
        $output = preg_replace('#([^:])//+#', '\\1/', $output);

        // Add the wrapper HTML if exists
        return $this->full_tag_open.$output.$this->full_tag_close;
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Parse attributes
     *
     * @param   array   $attributes
     * @return  void
     */
    public function _parse_attributes($attributes)
    {
        isset($attributes['rel']) OR $attributes['rel'] = TRUE;
        $this->_link_types = ($attributes['rel'])
                    ? array('start' => 'start', 'prev' => 'prev', 'next' => 'next')
                    : array();
        unset($attributes['rel']);

        $this->_attributes = '';
        foreach ($attributes as $key => $value)
        {
            $this->_attributes .= ' '.$key.'="'.$value.'"';
        }
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Add "rel" attribute
     *
     * @link    http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#linkTypes
     * @param   string  $type
     * @return  string
     */
    public function _attr_rel($type)
    {
        if (isset($this->_link_types[$type]))
        {
            unset($this->_link_types[$type]);
            return ' rel="'.$type.'"';
        }

        return '';
    }

}

/* End of file Pagination.php */
/* Location: ./system/libraries/Pagination.php */
```

And don't forget to set `$config['$display_prev_link']` and `$config['$display_next_link']` set to `true` or `false` according to your needs.

Good Luck!

Comment: Hi !!! I am newbie in codeigniter and I did as per your script. but it generates an error - 
Fatal error: Class 'CI_Pagination' not found in /var/www/HMVC_Test/application/libraries/MY_Pagination.php on line 3

Comment: @AlpeshTrivedi Check that in your application/config.php has a line $config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_'; and try again. It works great to me and I can only guess that one of your setting is messed up. Also I don't understand why you changes your library folder to libraries... change it back to its originally name and try again

Comment: thanks for your reply !! but I didn't change library to libraries, it came with codeigniter.  :)

Answer (score 7):

Example: http://www.friv100flash.com/

```
$config['base_url'] = base_url(); // xác định trang phân trang
$config['total_rows'] = $this->Game_model->count_all(); // xác định tổng số record
$config['per_page'] = 120; // xác định số record ở mỗi trang
$config['uri_segment'] = 1; // xác định segment chứa page number
$config['num_links'] = 7;

$config['display_pages'] = TRUE;
$config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;

//Encapsulate whole pagination 
$config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
$config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';

//First link of pagination
$config['first_link'] = 'First';
$config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>>';
$config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';

//Customizing the “Digit” Link
$config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';

//For PREVIOUS PAGE Setup
$config['prev_link'] = 'prev';
$config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';

//For NEXT PAGE Setup
$config['next_link'] = 'Next';
$config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';

//For LAST PAGE Setup
$config['last_link'] = 'Last';
$config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';

//For CURRENT page on which you are
$config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
$config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
$this->pagination->initialize($config);

if($this->uri->segment(1) == 0)
{
    $offset = 0;
}
else
{
    $offset = ($config['per_page'])*($this->uri->segment(1)-1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ci\system\libraries\Pagination.php

before

```
    if  ($this->prev_link !== FALSE AND $this->cur_page != 1)
    {
        if ($this->use_page_numbers)
        {
            $i = $uri_page_number - 1;
        }
        else
        {
            $i = $uri_page_number - $this->per_page;
        }


        if ($i == 0 && $this->first_url != '')
        {
            $output .= $this->prev_tag_open.'<a '.$this->anchor_class.'href="'.$this->first_url.'">'.$this->prev_link.'</a>'.$this->prev_tag_close;
        }
        else
        {
            $i = ($i == 0) ? '' : $this->prefix.$i.$this->suffix;
            $output .= $this->prev_tag_open.'<a '.$this->anchor_class.'href="'.$this->base_url.$i.'">'.$this->prev_link.'</a>'.$this->prev_tag_close;
        }

    }
```

after (ADD LAST 3 LINE)

```
    if  ($this->prev_link !== FALSE AND $this->cur_page != 1)
    {
        if ($this->use_page_numbers)
        {
            $i = $uri_page_number - 1;
        }
        else
        {
            $i = $uri_page_number - $this->per_page;
        }


        if ($i == 0 && $this->first_url != '')
        {
            $output .= $this->prev_tag_open.'<a '.$this->anchor_class.'href="'.$this->first_url.'">'.$this->prev_link.'</a>'.$this->prev_tag_close;
        }
        else
        {
            $i = ($i == 0) ? '' : $this->prefix.$i.$this->suffix;
            $output .= $this->prev_tag_open.'<a '.$this->anchor_class.'href="'.$this->base_url.$i.'">'.$this->prev_link.'</a>'.$this->prev_tag_close;
        }

    }
    else{
         $output .= '<span class="hidden">'.$this->prev_link.'</span>';
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't solve my problem since it doesn't includes $config['prev_tag_open'] & $config['prev_tag_close'] and address only the previous page only and not the next as well...

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter Pagination Library pagination.php

```
class CI_Pagination { 

public $limit;

public $active_page;

public $query;

public $url;

function run_query(){
  $CI= &get_instance();
  $query= $CI->db->query($this->query)->result_array();
  return $query;  
}

function result(){
  $CI= &get_instance();
  $limit_start=($this->active_page - 1) * $this->limit;
  $limit_end=$this->limit;
  $query=$this->query.' order by id desc limit '.$limit_start.','.$limit_end;
  $query= $CI->db->query($query)->result_array();
  return $query; 
}

function size(){
  return sizeof($this->run_query());
}


function page_number(){
    ?>
    <ul class="pagination  no-margin">
        <li class="prev <?php if($this->active_page <= '1'){echo 'disabled';}else{echo '';} ?>">
            <a href="<?= $this->url ?>page=<?= $this->active_page-1 ?>">
                <i class="ace-icon fa fa-angle-double-left"></i>
            </a>
        </li>

        <?php 

            if($this->active_page >=10){$i=$this->active_page-8;}else{$i=2;} 

            $end_point=ceil($this->size()/$this->limit);
        ?>

        <li class="<?php if($this->active_page==$i){echo 'active';} ?>">
            <a href="<?= $this->url ?>page=1">1</a>
        </li>

        <li class="<?php if($this->active_page<=10){echo 'hide';} ?>">
            <a href="<?= $this->url ?>page=<?= $this->active_page-1 ?>">...</a>
        </li>

        <?php $n=1; for($i;$i<=$end_point-1;$i++){ if($n++ >=10){break;}?>

            <li class="<?php if($this->active_page==$i){echo 'active';} ?>">
                <a href="<?= $this->url ?>page=<?= $i ?>"><?= $i ?></a>
            </li>

        <?php } ?>

        <li class="<?php if($this->active_page>=($end_point-5)){echo 'hide';} ?>">
                <a href="<?= $this->url ?>page=<?= $this->active_page+1 ?>">...</a>
        </li>

        <li class="<?php if($this->active_page==$i){echo 'active';} ?>">
                <a href="<?= $this->url ?>page=<?= $end_point .'">'. $end_point ?></a>
        </li>

        <li class="next <?php if($this->active_page >=ceil($this->size()/$this->limit)){echo'disabled';}?>">
            <a href="<?= $this->url ?>page=<?= $this->active_page+1 ?>">
                <i class="ace-icon fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
<?php
}
```

}

In Codeigniter controller

```
$this->load->library('pagination');
        $this->pagination->active_page = $page;
        $this->pagination->url = base_url('admins/popup?');
        $this->pagination->limit='50';
        $this->pagination->query='select * from contact where admin_id like "%'.$data["client_id"][0]["client_id"].'%"';
        $this->pagination->run_query();
        $data['pagination_data'] = $this->pagination->result();
```

IN Codeigniter View :

```
foreach ($pagination_data as $fet) { }
$this->pagination->page_number();
```

Jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            if($('#example >tbody >tr').length <=0){
              var row= document.getElementById("example").insertRow(-1);
              var cell1 = row.insertCell(0).colSpan=12;
              var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
              cell1.innerHTML = "Result Not Found !";
            }
        });
```

Comment: Use bootstrap and table id should be #example in foreach loop