# codeigniter pagination previous first and last links are hiding when there are only two pages, whereas i want to display all the links

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

there is a page which shows records from webpage, and using pagination for this page so i'm using in controller

```
    $config['per_page']=$sitepage;  
    $limit=$page;
    $pagesize= $config['per_page'];
    $config['display_pages'] = FALSE;
    $config['first_link'] = '<img src="'.base_url().'images/first.gif" title="first" /> ';
    $config['prev_link'] = '<img src="'.base_url().'images/left.gif"  title="prev"/>';
    $config['next_link'] = '<img src="'.base_url().'images/right.gif" title="next" />';
    $config['last_link'] = '<img src="'.base_url().'images/last.gif" title="last" />';
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
```

but if there are only 10 records and my pagination is 5 then only `next` is being displayed where as i need all the links to be displayed.

Comment: what is the image url generated for first and next link? check in html source

Comment: the links are working properly.. but only the working links are displayed like next and previous but not 4 of'em when there are less number of records

Comment: I asked yo check the image url. Not pagination url.

Comment: yes the images are working...

Comment: you have 10 records. so you are getting only two links next and prevous

Comment: exactly.. but i need to display the first and last links as well

Comment: first & last links are only displayed when your result has more than $config['num_links'] pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set false to display pages, then links won't displayed.

```
$config['display_pages'] = FALSE;
```

Remove this line in your code.

Comment: i did this before.. but this would only display the page numbers, which is not in my requirements i need the four links to be displayed.. :(

Comment: inspect your html element. your image source may be wrong.

Comment: I don't think so because all the images are displayed when lots of records are there.. and there were no image not found errors..

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16039129/270037  By default CI wont show the First and last link in your situation. So you have to modify the code as in this answer

Comment: Thank you that link helped me to do some changes.. and it worked.. :)