# Pagination First-Last link Disappeared

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

Respected,

I have implemented the pagination code in CodeIgniter.It is working fine.
But the issue is when i load page for first time it shows me two links(First 1 2 3 Last) ,number of pages.
But when i click on last page and come back to 3rd page.the 'FIRST' will be disappeared.

[My Controller Code](http://pastebin.com/7tiAAaFN)

[Pagination Lib](http://pastebin.com/42905nfg)

[**Live URL to Check**](http://store.hyperlink-iconcept.com/catagory/androidTopRated/A/30)

[What i Want is look like...](http://demo.codesamplez.com/codeigniter/pagination-demo/6)

Answer (score 0):

Ideally I would like to add this as a comment but I don't have enough reputation. However here is a link to a question to which the answer I believe will help you to achieve what you want to achieve. [Always show Previous & Next links using CodeIgniter Pagination Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16027480/always-show-previous-next-links-using-codeigniter-pagination-class)

Hopefully this helps you.