# Codeigniter 3.1.0 & Bootstrap Pagination Links

Tags: codeigniter

On my codeigniter pagination links I am using bootstrap 3 +

When I am on the very first link it hides the << which goes back to start when I click on it.

```
1 2 >>
```

> **Question** How can I make the codeigniter pagination all ways display `<<`   `>>` I have tried [Always show Previous & Next links using CodeIgniter Pagination Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16027480/always-show-previous-next-links-using-codeigniter-pagination-class) but is for CI2

```
$config['base_url'] = base_url('forum/?fid=' . $this->input->get('fid') . $url);
$config['total_rows'] = $this->thread_model->total_threads($this->input->get('fid'));
$config['per_page'] = $this->config->item('config_limit_admin');
$config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;

$config["full_tag_open"] = '<ul class="pagination">';
$config["full_tag_close"] = '</ul>';    
$config["first_link"] = "&laquo;";
$config["first_tag_open"] = "<li>";
$config["first_tag_close"] = "</li>";
$config["last_link"] = "&raquo;";
$config["last_tag_open"] = "<li>";
$config["last_tag_close"] = "</li>";
$config['next_link'] = '&raquo;';
$config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['next_tag_close'] = '<li>';
$config['prev_link'] = '&laquo;';
$config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['prev_tag_close'] = '<li>';
$config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
$config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
$config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';

$this->pagination->initialize($config);

$data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
```

Comment: Just note that your xxx_xxx_close tags should be </li> and not <li>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have just override the `create_links()` of core library in slightly different way to achieve this. So All you have to do is create a file name `My_Pagination.php` in`application/libraries` and put this code there (Code copied from `create_link()` method from core library `Pagination.php`)

`My_Pagination.php` file (Codeigniter 3.1.0)

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Pagination extends CI_Pagination {

public function create_links() {

    if ($this->total_rows == 0 OR $this->per_page == 0) {
        return '';
    }

    // Calculate the total number of pages
    $num_pages = (int) ceil($this->total_rows / $this->per_page);

    if ($num_pages === 1) {
        return '';
    }

    // Check the user defined number of links.
    $this->num_links = (int) $this->num_links;

    if ($this->num_links < 0) {
        show_error('Your number of links must be a non-negative number.');
    }

    // Keep any existing query string items.
    // Note: Has nothing to do with any other query string option.
    if ($this->reuse_query_string === TRUE) {
        $get = $this->CI->input->get();

        // Unset the controll, method, old-school routing options
        unset($get['c'], $get['m'], $get[$this->query_string_segment]);
    } else {
        $get = array();
    }

    // Put together our base and first URLs.
    // Note: DO NOT append to the properties as that would break successive calls
    $base_url = trim($this->base_url);
    $first_url = $this->first_url;

    $query_string = '';
    $query_string_sep = (strpos($base_url, '?') === FALSE) ? '?' : '&amp;';

    // Are we using query strings?
    if ($this->page_query_string === TRUE) {
        // If a custom first_url hasn't been specified, we'll create one from
        // the base_url, but without the page item.
        if ($first_url === '') {
            $first_url = $base_url;

            // If we saved any GET items earlier, make sure they're appended.
            if (!empty($get)) {
                $first_url .= $query_string_sep . http_build_query($get);
            }
        }

        // Add the page segment to the end of the query string, where the
        // page number will be appended.
        $base_url .= $query_string_sep . http_build_query(array_merge($get, array($this->query_string_segment => '')));
    } else {
        // Standard segment mode.
        // Generate our saved query string to append later after the page number.
        if (!empty($get)) {
            $query_string = $query_string_sep . http_build_query($get);
            $this->suffix .= $query_string;
        }

        // Does the base_url have the query string in it?
        // If we're supposed to save it, remove it so we can append it later.
        if ($this->reuse_query_string === TRUE && ($base_query_pos = strpos($base_url, '?')) !== FALSE) {
            $base_url = substr($base_url, 0, $base_query_pos);
        }

        if ($first_url === '') {
            $first_url = $base_url . $query_string;
        }

        $base_url = rtrim($base_url, '/') . '/';
    }

    // Determine the current page number.
    $base_page = ($this->use_page_numbers) ? 1 : 0;

    // Are we using query strings?
    if ($this->page_query_string === TRUE) {
        $this->cur_page = $this->CI->input->get($this->query_string_segment);
    } elseif (empty($this->cur_page)) {
        // Default to the last segment number if one hasn't been defined.
        if ($this->uri_segment === 0) {
            $this->uri_segment = count($this->CI->uri->segment_array());
        }

        $this->cur_page = $this->CI->uri->segment($this->uri_segment);

        // Remove any specified prefix/suffix from the segment.
        if ($this->prefix !== '' OR $this->suffix !== '') {
            $this->cur_page = str_replace(array($this->prefix, $this->suffix), '', $this->cur_page);
        }
    } else {
        $this->cur_page = (string) $this->cur_page;
    }

    // If something isn't quite right, back to the default base page.
    if (!ctype_digit($this->cur_page) OR ( $this->use_page_numbers && (int) $this->cur_page === 0)) {
        $this->cur_page = $base_page;
    } else {
        // Make sure we're using integers for comparisons later.
        $this->cur_page = (int) $this->cur_page;
    }

    // Is the page number beyond the result range?
    // If so, we show the last page.
    if ($this->use_page_numbers) {
        if ($this->cur_page > $num_pages) {
            $this->cur_page = $num_pages;
        }
    } elseif ($this->cur_page > $this->total_rows) {
        $this->cur_page = ($num_pages - 1) * $this->per_page;
    }

    $uri_page_number = $this->cur_page;

    // If we're using offset instead of page numbers, convert it
    // to a page number, so we can generate the surrounding number links.
    if (!$this->use_page_numbers) {
        $this->cur_page = (int) floor(($this->cur_page / $this->per_page) + 1);
    }

    // Calculate the start and end numbers. These determine
    // which number to start and end the digit links with.
    $start = (($this->cur_page - $this->num_links) > 0) ? $this->cur_page - ($this->num_links - 1) : 1;
    $end = (($this->cur_page + $this->num_links) < $num_pages) ? $this->cur_page + $this->num_links : $num_pages;

    // And here we go...
    $output = '';

    // Render the "First" link.
    if ($this->first_link !== FALSE && $this->cur_page > ($this->num_links + 1 + !$this->num_links)) {
        // Take the general parameters, and squeeze this pagination-page attr in for JS frameworks.
        $attributes = sprintf('%s %s="%d"', $this->_attributes, $this->data_page_attr, 1);

        $output .= $this->first_tag_open . '<a href="' . $first_url . '"' . $attributes . $this->_attr_rel('start') . '>'
                . $this->first_link . '</a>' . $this->first_tag_close;
    }

    // Render the "Previous" link.
    //if ($this->prev_link !== FALSE && $this->cur_page !== 1)
    if ($this->prev_link !== FALSE) {//REMOVED $this->cur_page !== 1
        $i = ($this->use_page_numbers) ? $uri_page_number - 1 : $uri_page_number - $this->per_page;

        $attributes = sprintf('%s %s="%d"', $this->_attributes, $this->data_page_attr, ($this->cur_page - 1));

        if ($i === $base_page || $this->cur_page == 1) {//ADDED $this->cur_page == 1
            // First page
            $output .= $this->prev_tag_open . '<a href="' . $first_url . '"' . $attributes . $this->_attr_rel('prev') . '>'
                    . $this->prev_link . '</a>' . $this->prev_tag_close;
        } else {
            $append = $this->prefix . $i . $this->suffix;
            $output .= $this->prev_tag_open . '<a href="' . $base_url . $append . '"' . $attributes . $this->_attr_rel('prev') . '>'
                    . $this->prev_link . '</a>' . $this->prev_tag_close;
        }
    }


    // Render the pages
    if ($this->display_pages !== FALSE) {
        // Write the digit links
        for ($loop = $start - 1; $loop <= $end; $loop++) {
            $i = ($this->use_page_numbers) ? $loop : ($loop * $this->per_page) - $this->per_page;

            $attributes = sprintf('%s %s="%d"', $this->_attributes, $this->data_page_attr, $loop);

            if ($i >= $base_page) {
                if ($this->cur_page === $loop) {
                    // Current page
                    $output .= $this->cur_tag_open . $loop . $this->cur_tag_close;
                } elseif ($i === $base_page) {
                    // First page
                    $output .= $this->num_tag_open . '<a href="' . $first_url . '"' . $attributes . $this->_attr_rel('start') . '>'
                            . $loop . '</a>' . $this->num_tag_close;
                } else {
                    $append = $this->prefix . $i . $this->suffix;
                    $output .= $this->num_tag_open . '<a href="' . $base_url . $append . '"' . $attributes . '>'
                            . $loop . '</a>' . $this->num_tag_close;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Render the "next" link
    //if ($this->next_link !== FALSE && $this->cur_page < $num_pages)
    if ($this->next_link !== FALSE) {//REMOVED $this->cur_page < $num_pages
        $i = ($this->use_page_numbers) ? $this->cur_page + 1 : $this->cur_page * $this->per_page;

        if($this->cur_page == $num_pages){//WHEN LAST LINK
            $i = $num_pages;
        }

        $attributes = sprintf('%s %s="%d"', $this->_attributes, $this->data_page_attr, $this->cur_page + 1);

        $output .= $this->next_tag_open . '<a href="' . $base_url . $this->prefix . $i . $this->suffix . '"' . $attributes
                . $this->_attr_rel('next') . '>' . $this->next_link . '</a>' . $this->next_tag_close;
    }

    // Render the "Last" link
    if ($this->last_link !== FALSE && ($this->cur_page + $this->num_links + !$this->num_links) < $num_pages) {
        $i = ($this->use_page_numbers) ? $num_pages : ($num_pages * $this->per_page) - $this->per_page;

        $attributes = sprintf('%s %s="%d"', $this->_attributes, $this->data_page_attr, $num_pages);

        $output .= $this->last_tag_open . '<a href="' . $base_url . $this->prefix . $i . $this->suffix . '"' . $attributes . '>'
                . $this->last_link . '</a>' . $this->last_tag_close;
    }


    $output = preg_replace('#([^:"])//+#', '\\1/', $output);


    return $this->full_tag_open . $output . $this->full_tag_close;
}

}
```

Just removed 2 condition

1. `$this->cur_page !== 1` (This is below // Render the "Previous" link COMMENT)
2. `$this->cur_page < $num_pages` (This is below // Render the "next" link COMMENT)

Added 2 condition

1. `if ($i === $base_page){...` changed this as `if ($i === $base_page || $this->cur_page == 1) {...`
2. Added this inside `if ($this->next_link !== FALSE) {...` condition

   ```
       if($this->cur_page == $num_pages){
           $i = $num_pages;
       }
   ```

None you have to do except putting this file in `libraries` directory and now your `<<` and `>>` links will show always even you may change it in config as normal configuration

Answer (score 2):

Well, you'll have to modify the `create_links` of the `Pagination` class. What I'd do it's extending the `system/libraries/Pagination.php` class with a MY_Pagination.php, so you override the behaviour and you can modify it accordingly to your preferences.

By the way, checking the class, I think you should look into lines 563 on:

```
    // Render the "First" link.
    if ($this->first_link !== FALSE && $this->cur_page > ($this->num_links + 1 + ! $this->num_links))
    {
        // Take the general parameters, and squeeze this pagination-page attr in for JS frameworks.
        $attributes = sprintf('%s %s="%d"', $this->_attributes, $this->data_page_attr, 1);
        $output .= $this->first_tag_open.'<a href="'.$first_url.'"'.$attributes.$this->_attr_rel('start').'>'
            .$this->first_link.'</a>'.$this->first_tag_close;
    }
```

You'll have to take care of the if condition to always render the link.